# jQuery conflict with other library (MooTools)

Tags: jquery, mootools

I'm having trouble implementing a small javascript that uses jQuery. The code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("span.question").hover(function () {
         $(this).append('<div class="tooltip"><p>This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.</p></div>');
     }, function () {
         $("div.tooltip").remove();
     });
 });
```

I've seen similar posts where the problem was said to be caused by a mootools javascript conflict. So I replaced each instance of '$' with 'jQuery' but the script still does nothing and no errors are shown in the firebug console. Would someone be able to indicate to me what the problem is?
Thanks.

Comment: can you post the code how you induded jQuery? and did you include it in the no conflict mode?

Comment: I've just tried using the code posted by Jehanzeb.Malik in the head section of my templates template.php file but to no avail. I've tried this with two of my Joomla installations but still can't get the script to function (or any custom javascript code using jQuery). I can't understand what the problem could be since the firebug console shows nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores them.

So you need to move the control back to `jQuery`. Then you will have to use `jQuery` instead of '$'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery("span.question").hover(function () {
            jQuery(this).append('<div class="tooltip"><p>This is a tooltip. It is typically used to explain something to a user without taking up space on the page.</p></div>');
        }, function () {
            jQuery("div.tooltip").remove();
        });
     });
</script>
```

**NOTE:** And do confirm that jQuery is only included once.

**EDIT:** I forgot to close `.ready` function. I fixed that. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxCNw/) link to see how it works.

Comment: I tried the code in the head section of the template file but the script still doesn't work. The firebug console said there were missing brackets but upon fixing there were no errors. I can't understand what the problem could be. I'll see what happens if I try it with another Joomla site.

Comment: @Danny Thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed that and added a fiddle link in the **EDIT** to show how it works.

Comment: @Danny Note that fiddle always adds the script in the head and run it. So technically it should work for you. It must be small thing that you might be over-looking. Take a step back and evaluate. That works for me. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I still can't get it to work. The firebug console says `$.noConflict` is not a function. Strangely, I can get it to work with my other joomla site by replacing all of the `$`s with `jQuery`. I'm stumped.

Comment: Make sure that `$.noConflict` is called after jquery is included.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write at the beginning of your code:

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```